# Exit not working inside function in SSH's script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, exit

I'm executing a local script, which executes a second script via SSH:

```
RES=$(ssh user@destination 'bash -s 2>&1' < remoteScript.sh)
```

I need the second script (remoteScript.sh) to exit with code 1 when I detect an error, which is why I built a function which is executed after some delicate calculations:

```
ErrorCheck()
{
    if [ ! "$?" = "0" ]
    then
            exit 1
    fi
}
```

Unfortunately, the exit 1 is behaving as a return instruction, as the remoteScript.sh execution continues. According to my testing this is related to using sudo su - {user} at the beginning of the remote script.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I make that function, end the remoteScript.sh?

**EDIT:**

I'm adding a very limited example of my remote script. I've tried running it locally and it works. It just fails when running via SSH.

```
sudo su - {user}
DelicateFunction()
{
    # The following instruction fails
    thisisanerror123
    ErrorCheck
}
ErrorCheck()
{
    if [ ! "$?" = "0" ]
    then
            exit 1
    fi
}
printf "Executing DelicateFunction\n"
DelicateFunction
printf "I should not print!"
```

Comment: Can you show how you call `ErrorCheck`? My guess is you're doing it in a subshell, or in a pipe, which implicitly creates a subshell.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem. The function as written is fine, so there's something going wrong in the surrounding context. Let's see a self-contained example script that shows the bug.

Comment: Not just not needed, but not guaranteed to work. The POSIX string equality operator is `=`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that won't exit is if it's running in a sub-shell.
`exit` is guaranteed to exit its shell.

Incidentally, you can write `ErrorCheck` a lot simpler:

```
ErrorCheck()
{
    [ $? = 0 ] || exit 1
}
```

Comment: I understand the issue comes from the fact that I'm using sudo su - {user} at the beginning of the script. If I don't switch user, the function works as expected. The issue is that I'm not allowed to connect directly using that user. I'm always force to switch it in the script.